# Labeling rows based on the condition in other rows

Tags: r, dplyr

Want to label rows with `type==NA` based on the condition in other rows.

The condition is;
Look for the `type!=NA` rows and use their sd_value to determine `type==NA` rows new label. `type2`

Such that

```
df <- data.frame(value = c(0.5,0.6,1,1.2), sd_value=c(0.1,0.5,0.2,0.8),
                 type = c("good", NA,"bad",NA))

value sd_value type
1   0.5      0.1 good
2   0.6      0.5   NA
3   1.0      0.2  bad
4   1.2      0.8   NA
```

2nd row value is inside of the 2*sd_value of `type=="good"` and 4th row value is inside of the 2*sd_value of `type=="bad"` so that NA rows in `type` column should be labeled 'good' and 'bad'.

I tried

```
library(dplyr)




  df%>%
  mutate(type2=ifelse(is.na(type),as.character(type[which(value>value-sd_value*2&value<value+sd_value*2)]),NA))



 value sd_value type type2
1   0.5      0.1 good  good
2   0.6      0.5   NA    NA
3   1.0      0.2  bad   bad
4   1.2      0.8   NA    NA
```

but the expected output should be

```
 value sd_value type type2
1   0.5      0.1 good  good
2   0.6      0.5   NA  good
3   1.0      0.2  bad   bad
4   1.2      0.8   NA   bad
```

How can assign type2 column that I wanted ?

thx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
 mutate(type2 = case_when(is.na(type) & 
                          (value > value - 2*sd_value & 
                           value < value - 2*sd_value) ~ "good",
                          is.na(type) ~ "bad",
                          TRUE ~ type))
```